# Time sync deviation and offsets between VM's in Azure (VMSS)

Tags: azure, time, synchronization, offset, azure-virtual-machine

We have been handling a rather peculiar issue with **clock offsets between VM's (Windows Server 2019) on Azure, that are hosted in the same region and datacenter, moreover in a VMSS**.

Several facts regarding the issue, after doing some experiments in the last three months:

- Have those issues in all of our environments: Test/Dev/Prod.
- Been checking the offsets using a reference NTP (The delta between the VM Clock and an NTP Time Server clock online, outside Azure)
- Our product is very time sensitive, so time skews and offsets between VM's can cause possible problems.
- Several times a day, the offset between VM's in the same VMSS can get to 1-3 seconds. We need to resync the clock on the VM's each time there is a problem.
- We've been keeping a monitor for all of the offsets using an outside log,
- Having 3 months of data, using an outside metrics program (Datadog) didn't give any hints. It just happens, several time a day, sometimes not.

**Would appreciate any ideas.**

Comment: have you read this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/time-sync

Comment: Indeed. But it didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: By default, Windows OS VM images are configured for w32time to sync from two sources: Could you Opt-in for host-only time sync. Mark the NTPClient provider as disabled. from that comment linked article?

Comment: Thank you. We are already using Host-Only time sync.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the solution by examining services logs.

1. w32time service was configured as "manual start" instead of delay-auto or auto. And though "Set time automatically" was "On", clock synchronization only happened after starting the service and resyncing. **So I've changed the Startup type of the Windows time service from Manual to Automatic (Delayed Start) using the following command:**

   &sc.exe config w32time start= delayed-auto
2. **Disabled Time Synchronization (service task) in Task Scheduler.**

   Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "SynchronizeTime" -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\Time Synchronization"

Time Skews are being fixed automatically and occur less often.